# SyntaxError in `$and` query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to dynamically create an `$and` query in mongodb. But I get error `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell)`. Is it not possible to create an `$and` query dynamically?

```
db.firstcoll.find({
        $and: [{
                Thing: {
                    $in: stuff
                }
            },
            {
                Thing: {
                    $ne: "One three"
                }
            },
            {
                Category: "Second"
            }
        ]
    }).forEach(function(doc1) {
        var words = doc1.Thing.split(' ');
        var NewQuery;
        if (words.length == 1) {
            NewQuery = {
                $and: [{
                        Thing: {
                            $regex: words[0]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        Category: doc1.Category
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
        if (words.length == 2) {
            NewQuery = {
                $and: [{
                    Thing: {
                        $regex: words[0]
                    }
                }, {
                    Thing: {
                        $regex: words[1]
                    }
                }, {
                    Category: doc1.Category
                }]
            }
        };

        db.secondcoll.find(
            NewQuery
        ).forEach(function(doc2) {
            print("stuff: ", doc2.stuff)

        })

    })
```

Comment: You have *Things* which neither 1 nor 2 words.

Comment: @AlexBlex I dont understand what you mean

Comment: You don't initialise `NewQuery` with any value, and define it only when `words.length == 1` or `words.length == 2`. In all other cases it is null.

Comment: @AlexBlex Pls assume that `words` are always either length 1 or 2. Still error :/